# Not all parameters were used in sql statement

Tags: python, mysql

```
def update_data(self):
    if (
        self.var_dep.get() == "Select Department"
        or self.var_std_name.get() == ""
        or self.var_std_id.get() == ""
    ):
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "All fields are required", parent=self.root)
    else:
        try:
            upadate = messagebox.askyesno(
                "Update", "Do you want to update this student details", parent=self.root
            )
            if upadate > 0:
                conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host="localhost",
                    username="root",
                    password="K2412@",
                    database="face_recognizerr",
                )
                my_cursor = conn.cursor()
                my_cursor.execute(
                    "update student set Dep=%s,course=%s,year=%s,semester=%s,Division=%s,Roll=%s,Gender=%s,Dob=%s,Email=%s,Phone=%s,Address=%s,Lecturer=%s,PhotoSample=%s where student_id=%s",
                    (
                        self.var_dep.get(),
                        self.var_course.get(),
                        self.var_year.get(),
                        self.var_semester.get(),
                        self.var_std_name.get(),
                        self.var_div.get(),
                        self.var_roll.get(),
                        self.var_gender.get(),
                        self.var_dob.get(),
                        self.var_email.get(),
                        self.var_phone.get(),
                        self.var_address.get(),
                        self.var_lecturer.get(),
                        self.var_radio1.get(),
                        self.var_std_id.get(),
                    ),
                )
            else:
                if not upadate:
                    return
            messagebox.showinfo(
                "Success",
                "Student details successfully update completed",
                parent=self.root,
            )
            conn.commit()
            self.fetch_data()
            conn.close()

        except Exception as es:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Due To:{str(es)}", parent=self.root)
```

I used %s instead of %d as requried by sql langauge

and I expect to to be to update my table while using a tkinter GUI BUT inserting new users to the database, it works fine though I cannot add date.

I need your help please, thank you.

Comment: can you pls format your code properly?

Comment: You are missing the value for Std_Name field in UPDATE statement, it seems

Answer (score 0):

You have missed adding column details for `self.var_std_name.get()`.
If then also you are not able to add date to your column then, you need to have a column of Type date or datetime in your table. Once you have that, you'll need to convert your date in a string format before inserting it to your database. To do this, you can use the datetime module's strftime formatting function.
Ex:-

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
id = 1
formated_date = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
cursor.execute('insert into table(id, date_created) values(%s, %s)', (id, formated_date))
```